# summable sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for a sequence $\beta_n\in(0,1)$ such that

(i)  $~ \prod_{n\in\mathbb N} \beta_n =0$,

(ii) $~\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} (1-\beta_n)< +\infty$.

Does such a sequence exist?

*edit:* i have changed to $\beta_n\in(0,1)$ instead of $\beta_n\in[0,1]$.

Comment: $\beta_{17}=0$, $\beta_i=1$ for $i\ne17$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was in the process of writing something more elaborate, but since yours is likely to be one of the $17$ simplest solutions one can think of I deleted mine.

Comment: Is there such a sequence when $0<\beta_n<1$ for each $n$

Comment: *With the appropriate hypotheses*, convergence of $\prod(1+a_n)$ is equivalent to convergence of $\sum a_n$.

Comment: No such example exists.  Any text that discusses infinite products surely includes this.  Perhaps written differently, see the topic "absolute convergence" for infinite series.

Comment: A convergent product in which all terms are nonzero can't take the value zero (by convention).

Comment: @Cocopuffs $\prod_{i=1}^n 1/2=1/2^n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @pritam that is correct. As soon as $a_n\le \theta<1$ for all $n>N_0$ you get convergence to zero. For this reason this case is, by definition, excluded if one talks about convergent infinite products. This is why Cocopuffs wrote 'by convetion'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality when (ii) holds that $\beta_n\geqslant1-\frac12\log2$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Then, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, $\beta_n\geqslant\mathrm e^{-2(1-\beta_n)}$, hence
$$
\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\beta_n\geqslant\exp\left(-2\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}(1-\beta_n)\right).
$$
Then (ii) implies that the RHS is positive hence the LHS is positive and (i) cannot hold.

Comment: thanks, I have also found this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158089/infinite-products-reference-needed), which deals with my question and more.