# Limit of $\prod_{i=1}^n (1-1/2^i)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the limit of the sequence $$s_n:=\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2^i} \right)$$

The sequence is decreasing and bounded below by $0$. I guess that the limit is $0$, is there any way to show this ? Or, is there any argument which shows that the limit is not zero ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit is definitely non-zero. Your product converges to a non-zero value, which is approximately $\approx 0.289$.

You should look up my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158089/infinite-products-reference-needed/158099#158099), why such infinite products can never be zero unless one of the term is itself zero. The product in your question is $\left(\dfrac12; \dfrac12\right)_{\infty}$ where $(a;q)_n$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).

Answer (score 3):

In fact the limit begins with $0.2887880950866024212788997219292307800889119\cdots$

To show that the limit is finite just consider the logarithm of the product so that the term added at each stage will be of order $2^{-i}$ making the series clearly convergent.

More generally (as indicated by Marvis first) we have ([Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product%20calculator&a=%2aC.product%20calculator-_%2aCalculator.dflt-&f2=1-z%5Ek&f=Product.prodfunction_1-z%5Ek&f3=1&f=Product.prodlowerlimit_1&f4=infinity&x=6&y=5&f=Product.produpperlimit_infinity&a=%2aFVarOpt.1-_%2a%2a-.%2a%2a%2aProduct.prodvariable---.%2a--)) :
$$\phi(z):=\prod_{i=1}^\infty 1-z^i= (z;z)_{\infty}$$

with $\phi$ the [Euler function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function).