# Infinite product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-a_{n}) = 0$ implies divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ or not?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, infinite-product

If $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-a_{n}) = 0$ then is it always true that  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ diverges? ($0 \leq a_{n} < 1) $

Comment: See also: [Infinite product problem: $\sum p_n< \infty$ implies $\prod (1-p_n)>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209108), [Suppose $1>a_n>0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-a_n)=0$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1650202), [How to prove $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n) = 0$ iff $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/519656), etc.

Answer (score 2):

If $a_n$ does not approach $0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges. So, assume $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0$

If $\displaystyle\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1-a_n) = 0$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}-\ln(1-a_n) = \infty$. Now, use the limit comparison test.

Comment: (+1) ... or just squeezing, since $a_n\geq -\frac{1}{2}\log(1-a_n)$ for every $a_n$ sufficiently close to zero.