# Suppose $1>a_n>0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-a_n)=0$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, infinite-product

Suppose $1>a_n>0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-a_n)=0$$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$.

*Proof of $\Rightarrow$:* Assume that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-a_n)=0$ converges. Well then at some $i$, $1-a_i=0$, which implies $a_i=1$. Knowing this if we were to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{\infty \text{ times}}=1\cdot \infty=\infty.$$

*Proof of $\Leftarrow$:* Assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$. How would I do this direction?

Comment: your proof is incorrect. You need to use the defintion of limit to prove it.

Comment: Can you state exactly what you mean?

Comment: Does your theorem work for $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: Make sure of your theorem?

Comment: Did you have a look at [frequent questions about infinite product](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-product?sort=frequent)? These two questions seem related, maybe you will find more: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519656/how-to-prove-prod-i-1-infty-1-a-n-0-iff-sum-i-1-infty-a-n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380094/sufficiency-and-necessity-of-convergence-of-sum-a-n-wrt-convergence-of-prod

Comment: BTW this seem to be closely related to your earlier questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649878/suppose-a-n0-for-n-in-mathbbn-prove-that-prod-n-1-infty-1a-n-c and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649989/suppose-1a-n0-for-n-in-mathbbn-prove-that-prod-n-1-infty-1-a-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention for infinite products is to say that the infinite product *diverges* to $0$ when the limit of partial products is $0$.

To get you on the correct track, here is one side of a correct proof.  Start with the well-known inequality $1-x \leqslant e^{-x}$ for $0 \leqslant x < 1$.

With $ 0 < a_n < 1$, it follows that for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$0 < P_m = \prod_{n=1}^m(1-a_n) \leqslant \prod_{n=1}^m e^{-a_n} = \exp\left(-\sum_{n=1}^ma_n\right).$$

Hence if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = \infty$ then $\lim_{m \to \infty} P_m = 0.$

Answer (score 3):

For the other direction: There is an easy generalization of Bernoulli's inequality that reads
$$
\prod_{n=N}^\infty (1-a_n)\ge 1-\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n
$$
so if the series converges one can find an $N$ such that the remainder is smaller than $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n<\frac12$ and thus
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-a_n)\ge\frac12\prod_{n=1}^{N-1} (1-a_n)>0.
$$