# Convergence of infinite product to zero implies series divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

I am stuck in one step of an application of Borel Cantelli Lemma.

I am trying to show the following :
if $a_n$ is a sequence such that $0 < a_n < 1$ for all $n$ then $\prod_{n=1}^\infty 1 - a_n = 0 \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = +\infty$. By using the log I can show that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty 1 - a_n = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1-a_n) = - \infty $ (since $1-a_n > 0, \forall n$) but I cannot conclude about the divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. Any hint ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria

Comment: If $a_n>\frac12$ infinitely often, $\sum a_n$ diverges. Thus one can assume that $0\leqslant a_n\leqslant\frac12$ for every $n$ and use the inequality $$e^{-2x}\leqslant1-x$$ for every $0\leqslant x\leqslant\frac12$.

Comment: Mmh I see, we use the equality then use the log ($-2a_n \leq log(1-a_n)$) and then sum over everything to conclude ? Thank you.

Comment: There are a few posts about this on this site, for example: [Infinite product problem: $\sum p_n< \infty$ implies $\prod (1-p_n)>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209108) or [How to prove $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n) = 0$ iff $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/519656), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$, given $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ there exists $N$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n < \epsilon$, and for all $m > N$

$$\prod_{n= N}^m(1-a_n) > 1 - \sum_{n=N}^ma_n > 1 - \epsilon  > 0$$

Comment: Ok I see that prove my point in that way $\prod_{n= 1}^\infty(1-a_n)$ cannot be zero but how do you prove $\prod_{n= N}^m(1-a_n) > 1 - \sum_{n=N}^ma_n$ ?

Comment: @DimitriMeunier: $(1-a_N)(1-a_{N+1}) = 1 - (a_N + a_{N+1}) + a_N a_{N+1} > 1 - (a_N + a_{N+1})$.  By induction $\prod_{n= N}^{m+1} (1- a_n) = \prod_{n= N}^{m} (1- a_n) (1 - a_{m+1}) > ( 1 - \sum_{n=N}^m a_n)(1 - a_{m+1}) > \ldots$.