# Infinite Product is converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, products, infinite-product

I am adding this problem since it is interesting and valuable to be verified here:

> Prove that the infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+u_k)$, wherein $u_k>0$, converges if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} u_k$ converges. What about the inverse problem?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: See also this blog post: [Convergence of Infinite Products](http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/convergence-of-infinite-products/) by Jim Belk
or [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158089/infinite-products-reference-needed/158099#158099) by Marvis.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thank you for noting me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $u_k > 0$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n u_k  \leq \prod_{k=1}^n (1+u_k) \leq \exp \left(\sum_{k=1}^n u_k \right)$$
Hence, if $u_k>0$, we have that$\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1+u_k)$ converges iff $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k$ converges.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but are you using $1+x\leq \text{exp}(x)$ for $x>0$. And what about the inverse direction? Thanks Marvis.

Comment: @BabakSorouh Yes. I am using the fact that $1+x \leq \exp(x)$. What do you mean by the inverse direction?

Comment: It is done. I see "iff" above in the answer. :)