# Is there a limit to the sum of non-trivial factors of N divided by N

Tags: divisor-sum

For example [Divisor function on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sigma_1(60)-61)%2F60)

Is there an upper limit on the answer?

Comment: Does $\prod_p\left(1+\frac1p\right)$ converge?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown   see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349588/how-would-i-find-a-number-where-sum-d-mid-nd-100n/349783#349783  The sequence of primorials works for this. We get smaller numbers for a fixed large ratio with the Colossally Abundant numbers, at the price of intricate programs to get specific numbers. I found an explicit CA number with ratio just over 30.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  why shark?

Comment: If you repost your question "Wondering if this function exists, or can exist", I will post an answer. Sorry to hijack this question to post a message, but there's no other way.

Comment: Ok, I've reposted the question, thanks for your input.