# $\sum|a_n|^2<\infty$ and $\sum a_n<\infty$ implies $\sum\log(1+a_n)$ converges

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

Note that all elements are complex numbers. Suppose we know $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^2\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$converge. How can we conclude $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log(1+a_n)$ converges? This is an effort to prove that $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+a_n)$$converges.

If I knew that $\sum a_n$ was absolutely convergent, then I think I'd be able to use the power series expansion of $\log(1+a_n)$ and interchange summations. However, I don't think this is the intended method of solution. Will someone help me with this homework problem?

**Update:** Other work I've done so far:

Disregarding finitely many terms if necessary, we can assume $|a_n|<\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$. Thus, we know $0\leq|a_n-\log(1+a_n)|<|a_n|^2$, so by comparison, we know $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n-\log(1+a_n)|$ converges. Since it is absolutely convergent, it is convergent, so now we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left( a_n-\log(1+a_n)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log(1+a_n),$$therefore the series is convergent. Is this correct?

Comment: [This is related.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158089/infinite-products-reference-needed/158099#158099)

Comment: Note that, $\ln(1+a_n)< a_n $.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I don't think that works since $a_n\in\Bbb C$. If they were real numbers, I think you are correct.

Comment: @Clayton: $\ln(1+|a_n|)<|a_n|$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I believe that statement, but unfortunately, we don't know $\sum|a_n|$ is convergent. Thanks for the persistence, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that, for small $x$,
$$\log(1+x)=x+\epsilon(x) |x|^2, \qquad |\epsilon(x)|\le 1,$$
to express $\sum_n \log(1+a_n)$ as a sum of two convergent series.

Comment re updated question:  Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Excellent! I was about to ask about the progress of my solution when you updated (your way seems perfectly reasonable as well, I just didn't know/see that beforehand). +$1$