# Define $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by $a_n:=\prod_{k=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{k^{1+c}})$. Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ hold?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $c\in \mathbb{R},c>0$ and define the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by $a_n:=\prod_{k=2}^n(1-\frac{1}{k^{1+c}})$. Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ hold?

Comment: @GEdgar: I'm sorry, I want to exclude the trivial case with a factor equal to zero and the product runs through the values of $k=2$ to $n$

Comment: Hands-on, purely real, approach: for every $x$ small enough, $$e^{-2x}\leqslant1-x\leqslant e^{-x}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite product
$$
\prod \left(1-\frac{1}{k^{1+c}}\right)
$$
converges absolutely, which means the series
$$
\sum\frac{1}{k^{1+c}}
$$
converges absolutely.

So a theorem says that, if you ignore any factor which is equal to zero, then the partial products
$$
\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{k^{1+c}}\right)
$$
converge to a non-zero value.

For the theorem, consult a text on complex analysis.  It seems watered-down presentations (like Wikipedia) do not include this...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm surprised that complex analytic methods are needed, because all terms are real. Has this theorem a specific name?

Comment: Complex analytic methods are not required.  But it is included in complex analysis texts, since they cannot assume the reader already knows it, but it is used in complex analysis.

Comment: The proof is basically: for a complex number close enough to zero, we have $|z|/2 < |\log(1+z)| \le |z|$.  References are listed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158089/infinite-products-reference-needed