# Good Book including Summations extensively

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

do you know any books that contains Summations extensively ? I read the appendix in Cormen and in Knuth's Fundamentals but I want more information and examples ?

Comment: If you want some book which has many exercises, you could have a look at books recommended here:
[Suggest books in calculus to improve problem solving skills](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170196/suggest-books-in-calculus-to-improve-problem-solving-skills)

Comment: This question is similar to yours: [Good book for self-learning sequence and series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29477/good-book-for-self-learning-sequence-and-series)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can consider the two Dover books:

1. Infinite Sequences and Series, AUTHOR:  Konrad Knopp, Publication Date:  June 1956, ISBN:  0486601536
2. Infinite Series, AUTHOR:  James M Hyslop, Publication Date:  February 2006, ISBN:  0486450333

You can probably find a site to peruse examples in the books and see if the style works for you.

~A

Comment: Thank goodness for (**inexpensive**) Dover Publications!

Comment: I love how they take excellent books and give them a second life! Yes, very slow night indeed!

Answer (score 2):

L. B. W. Jolley, Summation of Series.