# Good book for convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, convergence-divergence, book-recommendation

Can anybody please suggest me a good book for convergence of series where I could find good questions on sum of series, sum of alternating series etc. I already have solved standard books like Tom apostol's calculus. Knopp's theory etc. Basically I'm looking for a book having more questions and less chit-chat. I want to solve as much problems as I can.

Comment: Somewhat related question: [Good book for self-learning sequence and series](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29477).

Comment: You might be interested in the first volume of [Kaczor-Nowak](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170196/suggest-books-in-calculus-to-improve-problem-solving-skills/170205#170205).

Answer (score 5):

> I recommend the study of **[Real Infinite Series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857456)** by Daniel D. Bonar and Michael J. Khoury.
>
> - The first two chapters **Introduction to Infinite Series** and **More Sophisticated Techniques** provide a firm ground of basic convergence tests and some more sophisticated results which is not that often presented in introductory material.

To get an  idea  what  is addressed by *more sophisticated* we can e.g. find in section 2.4 the notation 2.15 stating:

- Define $\log_{(0)}x=x,\log_{(1)}x=\log x,\log_{(2)}x=\log(\log x)$, and, inductively, $\log_{(n+1)}x=\log(\log_{(n)}x)$.
- *Theorem 2.16 (Abel-Dini Scale)* For each integer $k$, the series
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{n\log_{(1)}n\log_{(2)}n\cdots\log_{(k)} n\left(\log_{(k+1)}n\right)^\alpha}
  \end{align*}
  converges if $\alpha >1$ and diverges if $\alpha \leq 1$, where $N$ is taken large enough for   the   iterated logarithms to be  defined.

> - The third chapter **The Harmonic Series and Related Results** presents nice information about the harmonic series and friends. E.g.

- *Theorem 3.17* Let $B$ be the set of positive integers whose decimal representation do not contain the digit $9$. Then the series
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n\in B}\frac{1}{n}
  \end{align*}
  converges.

Here we are at a border line with the divergent harmonic series on one side and related series where we ask if they are also divergent or not.

The first three chapters provide a good basis for the study of  even more sophisticated series organized in three following chapters.

> - Chapter 4 **Intriguing Results** provides $107$ so-called gems of different nature.

Gem $29$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^n}=\int_0^1x^x\,dx
\end{align*}

Gem $102$: For each real number $x$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}
\end{align*}
converges.

> - Chapter 5 **Series and The Putnam Competition** presents challenging problems about series and their solutions.
> - Chapter 6 **Final Diversions** gives some additional nice examples grouped in sections: Puzzles, Visuals, Fallacious Proofs and the last called Fallacies, Flaws and Flimflam.

This book is also worth reading for its interesting and informative appendices:

> - **Appendix A: $101$ True or False questions**

This is a good possibility to check what do we *really* know about series.

- Example: T/F $39$ 
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
  \end{align*}
  is a divergent series.
- Example: T/F $40$ The Root Test cannot alone be used to determine conditional convergence.

Finally I would like to point at

> - **Appendix C: References**

Here we obtain information grouped in

- Books on Infinite Series
- Books with Excellent Material on Infinite Series
- Sources for Excellent Problems Related to Infinite Series
- Pleasurable Reading
- Journal Articles

Answer (score 4):

Classical books are quite good when it comes to basic problems on convergence and divergence. Try *Pólya's and Szegö's Problems and theorems in Mathematical Analysis* which is a great treasurehouse of problems. *Knopp's Theory and Applications of Infinite Series* is good for applications and summability methods. *William F. Osgood's Introduction to infinite series* and *Bromwich's Introduction to the theory of Infinite series* are also great classics. A modern work of interest is *Titu Andreescu and T-L Radulescu's Problems in Real Analysis* which gives a great source of Problems and further references.